# file handler pointing to nil in storyboard swift

Tags: swift, storyboard, binaryfiles

I tried to make a file handler pointing to a binary file in my Swift storyboard app with fopen(, "rb"). But it returns a nil pointer even though I provide the full complete path to the binary file. The same lines of codes with the same path works in the Command Line App version of the same code.

I tried changing the info.plist file of the storyboard app to make "Supports opening documents in place" to yes, still no luck !

Does anybody know what might be the possible reason for this breakdown only with the storyboard version in loading binary files ?